# Fetch file and convert JavaScript array into PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, data-conversion

I've been searching for a few days now, trying to figure out the best way to solve a problem: I want to fetch a JavaScript file from e.g. GitHub and convert a JavaScript array into PHP.

My first idea was to fetch the page (raw.githubusercontent.com) with PHP (file_get_contents) on server side and then parse it. But it's a multidimensional array, so I think this is complicated and not very flexible.

---

Example

In JavaScript only the keys are relevant (e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxx/example.js)

```
var cars = {
    'Saab': {
        'Blue': true,
        'Green': true,
        ...
    },
    'Volvo': {
        'Brown': true
    },
    'BMW': {
        'Black': true
    },
    ...
}
```

In PHP the content should be combined as a string array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'SaabBlue'
    [1] => 'SaabGreen'
    [2] => 'VolvoBrown'
    [3] => 'BMWBlack'
    ...
)
```

I would be happy if someone had <del>an idea</del> a short hint ;)

---

**Update:**

I think I will do this server side with PHP.

```
$arr = array();

// fetch the file
$content = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxx/example.js');

// remove all comments and unnecessary lines with RegEx
$content = preg_replace(<RegEx Expression>, '', $content);

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $content) as $line){
    // filter with strpos and/or preg_match
    // [x][ ][ ]
    if ( filter ) {
        $m = explode("'", $line);
    // [ ][x][ ]
    } else if ( anyfilter) {
        $n = explode("'", $line);
    // [ ][ ][x]
    } else if ( filter ){
        $o = explode("'", $line);
        $str = $m[1] . $n[1] . $o[1];
        array_push($arr, $str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to do like `const fd = new FormData; fd.append('data', JSON.stringify(cars)); const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest; xhr.open('POST', 'yourPage.php'); xhr.onload = function(){ const respObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); } xhr.send(fd);`? In PHP `<?php if(isset($_POST['data'])){ $obj = json_decode($_POST['data']); /* do stuf with $obj like $obj->Saab */ } ?>`

Comment: _“I would be happy if someone had an idea”_ - so you don’t have _any_, after being at this “for days” now? Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, we always want to see you make an actual attempt first. We can help you figure out problems with your chosen approach, but we are not here to do _all_ of the work for you.

Comment: @CBroe Don't panic, I don't expect a complete solution, that's why I have only given exemplary data and only minimal information. But yes, I should have asked differently instead of "does anyone have an idea", e.g. "does anyone have an idea where I could start". My idea was to fetch the page with PHP on server side and then parse it. But it's a multidimensional array, so I think this is complicated and not very flexible. I don't think I'm the first one with such a problem, so I searched, first search engines, then the well-known platforms directly (Stackoverflow, GitHub, GitLab and so on).

Answer (score -1):

Set all the variables into cookies.

```
document.cookie = "cars_Saab_Blue="+cars.Saab.Blue;
```

Do something similar (dpending on the situation) and set everything into 1 or more cookies.
Now by using `$_COOKIE['cars_Saab_Blue']` you can get the cookie and use it wherever you want,